# How far in the future can I reschedule the flight?

Tags: bookings

How far in the future can I reschedule the flight?
I bought a tickets last year at AirFrance, I took the first leg but due to some circumstances I can't take the second.
Jul28th passing one year since the original 2nd leg schedule, AirFrance don't want to reschedule it to December (when I want it), they claim max by one year it can be rescheduled.
Tickets have been bought by Expedia - not at AirFrance directly.
What to do?

Comment: What do you currently have? A ticket with a future date? A “open” ticket with no date”? A credit? A voucher? Is it redeemable to cash? What was the cause for the postponement (e.g. Covid-related or other reason)? What were the terms of the ticket (flexible, semi-flexible, etc.)?

Answer (score 6):

> What to do?

Read the fare rules of your ticket. These spell out the exact rules conditions for changes, cancellations, refunds, change fees, vouchers etc and these vary a lot depending on the exact type of ticket that you bought. There is no such thing as a "normal" ticket, they all are different.

Chances are though, that the Air France agent did exactly that and that the rules determine that you can't make that change. If you find otherwise, you can call them again and show them your fare rules.

If you can't do the change you can consider cancelling and making a new booking. Whether that's reasonable or not depends, again, on the fare rules.

You actually got lucky that Air France talked to you in the first place, they could have just sent you back to Expedia.

Comment: Tickets from 3rd parties usually have far more restrictions and are way less flexible. OP really did get lucky.